# jQuery calendar date range minDate of second calendar +5 days

Tags: javascript, jquery, calendar

I have two jQuery calendar fields which the user must select a 'from' date and a 'to' date. I am able to restrict the users input on the first calendar to the current date, however how would i make it so that the second calendars date has to be atleast +5 days in the future of the first calendars date.

Here is my code.

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

        var from = $( "#from" ).datepicker({
            defaultDate: "today",
            changeMonth: true,
            required: true,
            numberOfMonths: 1,
            minDate: 0,
            dateFormat: 'd-M-y',
            onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
                $( "#to" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", selectedDate );
            }

        });
        var to = $( "#to" ).datepicker({
            defaultDate: "today",
            changeMonth: true,
            required: true,
            numberOfMonths: 1,
            minDate: 0,
            dateFormat: 'd-M-y',
            onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
                $( "#from" ).datepicker( "option", "maxDate", selectedDate );
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the days from the first calendar and add five days to it.

Like,

```
$('#to').datepicker({
    onSelect: function(dateVal) {
        var newDate= $.datepicker.parseDate('mm/dd/yy', dateVal);
        newDate.setDate(newDate.getDate() + 5);
        $('#to').val(newDate);
     }
});
```